# Perl Module::Load fails

Tags: perl, plugins, module

I tried to using Module::Load to dynamically load plugin from directory, but it doesn't work, even after maximal simplifing the code.
Main file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Load;

Module::Load::load_remote('Package', 'plugins/Blank.pm') or die;
```

plugins/Blank.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package plugins::Blank;

use strict;
use warnings;

1;
```

But it still die. When i remove '...or die' part, it no dies, but Package still not loaded.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: It die only if I keep 'or die' part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Module::Load::load_remote` dies when failing, but does not return anything. Your example works fine for me, and the package is loaded. If it doesn't load the package it should die inside `load_remote`. `load_remote` only loads the functions that are exported into the other namespace. It also only seem to work if the other module is loaded as a module name, instead of a filename:

`load.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Load;

Module::Load::load_remote("Package","plugins::Blank","hw");
Package::hw();
```

`plugins/Blank.pm`:

```
package plugins::Blank;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);

our @EXPORT_OK = qw(hw);

sub hw {
    print "Hello World\n";
}

1;
```

Outputs:

> Hello World

But to achieve what you want you can probably use an approach like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Load;

my $pkg = 'plugins::Blank';
Module::Load::load($pkg);
$pkg->hw();
```

Comment: Yes, plugins::Blank::hw works, but Package::hw not.
Cause module and sub name I'm reading from config file, I need to can call sub from module without knowing module name on compile stage.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. Maybe you should update your question to ask what you really want to know.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted.